# Как получить id всех авторов блога Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Я пишу виджет в котором пользователь сможет в radio выбрать автора и в виджете выведется аватар админа и описание.

```
wp_list_authors()
```

К сожалению не дает Id. Использовать для вывода информации хочу функцию `get_the_author_meta` которая требует id, если вне цикла. Может есть другой способ?

Answer (score 2):

> Может есть другой способ?

Функция [the_author_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) позволить получить ID

Но `wp_list_authors` итак работает вне цикла. См [доп. на русском](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_authors)

Answer (score 1):

```
$args  = array(
    'role' => 'Author',
    'orderby' => 'display_name'
);

$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();
if (!empty($authors))
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($authors as $author)
    {
        $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);
        echo '<li>'.$author->ID.' '.$author_info->user_email.' '.$author_info->last_name.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo 'No authors found';
}
```